# create @InvocableMethod inside class that implemented Batchable and invoke new instance to start

Tags: batch, visual-workflow, invocable-method

the main idea is to invoke @invocableMethod from flow and start Batch without creating separate class to be able to start batch

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An InvocableMethod must be static, so you can't not create an instance. You can, however, combine the logic of both in to a single class. This self-contained example will demonstrate.

```
public class q346460 implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    @InvocableMethod(description='Demo') public static String[] doThing(String[] input) {
        Database.executeBatch(new q346460());
        return input;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        
    }
}
```

Realistically, of course, you'll add whatever properties, etc to make the batch work as you desire, but the point is, you don't need two separate classes.

Comment: @Mossi Hey, thanks for reaching out. This code is literally in my dev org, and it's still running great! If you need further assistance, please ask a new question, give me a link, and I'll check it out for you, or you can send me an email and I'll be happy to look at this over the weekend for you.